# Angular 11 httpClient sequential requests

Tags: javascript, angular, synchronization, angular-httpclient

I have a front end that needs to add an array of items via a rest end point.

I can make a single call well enough and I believe that I understand the basics of subscribing to an observable. Indeed, I can successfully code a single request and properly process the response.

What I don't know is how to encapsulate several calls to the server. I want a function that returns an observable so that it acts like a single call.

It is important that the status is known and that it does actually insert.

```
// the complete payload.
export class SignupDto {
  companyInfo: CompanyInfo;
  storeInfo: StoreDto [];
  constructor(storeCount: number) {
    this.companyInfo = new CompanyInfo();
    this.storeInfo = new Array(storeCount);
  }
}



// my attempt.
 public postCompanyInfo(store: SignupModel) {
    const payload = MappingService.MapToPayload(store);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const config = { headers: headers, observe: "response" as 'body' };
    const Path = 'signup/';
    const URL = `${this.Protocol_Domain_Port}${Path}`;
    this.httpClient.post(URL, payload.companyInfo, config).subscribe(
      (resp: any) => { if( resp.status === 201 ) { this.onInsertStores(payload.storeInfo, resp._links.stores.href); } },
    )
  }

  public onInsertStores(storeInfo: StoreDto [], URL: string) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const config = { headers: headers, observe: "response" as 'body' };
    if( !!storeInfo && storeInfo.length > 0 ) {
      this.httpClient.post(URL, storeInfo[0], config).subscribe(
          (resp: any) => { if( resp.status === 201 ) { storeInfo.shift(); this.onInsertStores(storeInfo, URL); } },
        );
    }
  }
```

The company does post but then the stores fail down deep in the subscriber.js call stack.

```
catch (err) {
    this.unsubscribe();
    if (config.useDeprecatedSynchronousErrorHandling) {
        throw err;
```

I thought that I could use a sort of recursive solution but even if that worked I don't know how to return a status code at the end for either success or failure.

So, I need a way to first insert the company info, then sequentially insert each store. If there's a failure, stop and return that error. Or, if they all make it, then return success.

I came across something called a pipe mapper but honestly, I didn't understand it. So, I don't know if it would even solve my problem.

Just in case it helps, here's a mockup of what I'm trying to send.

```
{
  "companyInfo": {
    "companyAddress": {
      "address1": "1515 Elm St.",
      "address2": "Other Suit",
      "city": "Out of Dallas",
      "state": "TN",
      "zipcode": "77733"
    },
    "bankAddress": {
      "address1": "1717 Elm St.",
      "address2": "Broken Suit",
      "city": "USSN Dallas",
      "state": "LA",
      "zipcode": "33377"
    },
    "companyName": "Test Company is my name!",
    "companyTaxID": "999-99-9999",
    "bankAccountNumber": "1000000001",
    "bankRoutingNumber": "2000000002",
    "bankName": "We got yo cash!",
    "bankTelephone": "(666) 555-1212",
    "bankFax": "(555) 555-1212",
    "accountingContactFirstName": "Testitch",
    "accountingContactLastName": "McTestersen",
    "accountingContactEmail": "Testitch.McTestersen@Testy.co",
    "accountingContactTelephone": "(444) 555-1212",
    "accountingContactFax": "(333) 555-1212"
  },
  "storeInfo": [
    {
      "storeAddress": {
        "address1": "1313 Elm St.",
        "address2": "Spare Suit",
        "city": "Near Dallas",
        "state": "TX",
        "zipcode": "70033"
      },
      "storeName": "Test Co.",
      "customerStoreID": "Test Co Stores #0",
      "email": "Test@Testy.co",
      "telephone": "(888) 555-1212",
      "fax": "(777) 555-1212",
      "storeType": "AUTO_FULL_SERVICE",
      "posType": "SCANMASTER",
      "mnspType": "PAYSAFE"
    },
    {
      "storeAddress": {
        "address1": "1313 Elm St.",
        "address2": "Spare Suit",
        "city": "Near Dallas",
        "state": "TX",
        "zipcode": "70033"
      },
      "storeName": "Test Co.",
      "customerStoreID": "Test Co Stores #1",
      "email": "Test@Testy.co",
      "telephone": "(888) 555-1212",
      "fax": "(777) 555-1212",
      "storeType": "AUTO_FULL_SERVICE",
      "posType": "SCANMASTER",
      "mnspType": "PAYSAFE"
    },
    {
      "storeAddress": {
        "address1": "1313 Elm St.",
        "address2": "Spare Suit",
        "city": "Near Dallas",
        "state": "TX",
        "zipcode": "70033"
      },
      "storeName": "Test Co.",
      "customerStoreID": "Test Co Stores #2",
      "email": "Test@Testy.co",
      "telephone": "(888) 555-1212",
      "fax": "(777) 555-1212",
      "storeType": "AUTO_FULL_SERVICE",
      "posType": "SCANMASTER",
      "mnspType": "PAYSAFE"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want the response once all request are completed, or you want to patch your top level company entity as new store info data is coming?

Also if i got the idea right, you want to have one call for company and multiple calls for stores, based on parameters inside the company info?